# nfs: kernel server not accepting mount (rpcinfo: RPC: Timed out)

Tags: linux, nfs, hanging

I have an nfs-server that halfway hangs now and then. On server l this works:

```
# uname -a
Linux l 3.2.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP Sat Feb 11 08:41:32 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# showmount  -e l
Export list for l:
/disk/l 192.168.0.0/16
# mount l:/disk/l /mnt/disk/
# ls /mnt/disk
```

So it seems nfs works from server l to server l.

On server e:

```
# uname -a
Linux e 3.2.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP Sat Feb 11 08:41:32 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# showmount -e l
Export list for l:
/disk/l 192.168.0.0/16
# mount l:/disk/l /mnt/disk/
<<hangs>>
```

I have stop-started the `/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server` on server l, and mounting l:/disk/l on another dir still hangs on server e.

After booting server l I can mount on server e and everything is fine. But I would like to avoid the reboot as that disturbs users.

How can I kick the nfs-kernel-server so hard that it actually restarts completely and not just half-way restarts as seen above?

Edit:

I have also restarted portmap.

When I restart nfs-kernel-server it spends a lot of time after printing 'nfsd'. It seems it is hanging at: /usr/bin/rpcinfo -u localhost nfs 3

```
# /usr/bin/rpcinfo -u localhost nfs 3
rpcinfo: RPC: Timed out
program 100003 version 3 is not available
```

My other NFS servers say:

```
program 100003 version 3 ready and waiting
```

So that could be related to the problem.

Edit 2:

I tried removing and re-installing portmap and nfs-kernel-server. No luck.

So I mucked around with `rpcinfo` and did `rpcinfo -d <<all services>> <<all versions>>` so the output is now:

```
# rpcinfo -p
program vers proto   port
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
100024    1   udp  58796  status
100024    1   tcp  48139  status
100005    1   udp  48989  mountd
100005    1   tcp  52848  mountd
100005    2   udp  48989  mountd
100005    2   tcp  52848  mountd
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
```

Restarting nfs-kernel-server no longer pauses during /usr/bin/rpcinfo -u localhost nfs 3:

```
# /usr/bin/rpcinfo -u localhost nfs 3
rpcinfo: RPC: Program not registered
program 100003 version 3 is not available
```

Also I can no longer mount the local nfs on the local machine. I imagine that I some how need to register nfs in rpcinfo. Restarting nfs-kernel-server does not do that (or if it does, it does not work). `showmount -e` still works.

Comment: add the following (no_root_squash,rw,async,subtree_check)
to become : /disk/l 192.168.0.0/16(no_root_squash,rw,async,subtree_check)

Comment: This makes no difference.

Comment: do you have any kind of firewall ?

Comment: No firewall between the machines.

Comment: And the machines worked fine Friday. A reboot is known to help, but does not permanently solve the issue, so I would like a way to avoid rebooting.